# Discord API giving errors when trying to import it

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, discord, discord.py

I've been trying to get the Discord API installed and working but I can't for the life of me figure out how.

The first thing I tried was to simply install the Discord API using
`py -m pip install discord`
It installed but when I imported it, I got this error

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .client import Client, AppInfo, ChannelPermissions
  File "C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .state import ConnectionState
  File "C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 36, in <module>
    from . import utils, compat
  File "C:\Users\Harry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\compat.py", line 32
    create_task = asyncio.async
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I later found out that this was an error caused by an older version of the Discord API, so I tried to upgrade it using `py -m pip install --upgrade discord`
It seemed to work fine but I still got the same error when importing the library

So the next thing I tried was to uninstall the Discord API and reinstalling it. But when I tried to re-install it, it said it was already installed.

So I manually went into the Lib\site-packages folder and deleted both folders. Still, when trying to install it, nothing. Still said it was installed.

I even re-installed Python entirely, and Python still said that Discord was installed.

And I still got the same error while importing Discord.

I am honestly clueless at this point on how to get it working. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current release version of Discord-py is not compatible with Python 3.7, see e.g. [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/1648).
The authors suggest [switching to the `rewrite` version of the library](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html).

If you want to try that,

```
python -m pip install -U https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/archive/rewrite.zip#egg=discord.py[voice]
```

should work. You can also just use Python 3.6 instead of 3.7.